# graph path on hadoop with python

Tags: python, dictionary, hadoop, reduce

Hy guys, i have to write an algorithm in python with the map reduce paradigm that has to run on hadoop:

Let us assume that given a directed graph G = (V,E), an edge (v,u) ∈ E means that v is
following u, or that v has declared u being his friend, therefore u has the potential to influence v (but not necessarily the other way around). Now, given a network G = (V,E) and a node v ∈ V , we want to find all the nodes u such that there exists a path from v to u of length at most 3. Design and implement an algorithm for Hadoop that finds all such nodes. Assume that the input file(s)
give the adjacency list for each node, that is, they are of the form v:u1 ,u2 ,u3 . . .
where v is a node and each ui corresponds to the edge (v,ui ).

I have not idea how to implement map and reduce tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob

mrjob takes care of packaging up your code and handling the streaming API. You just have to write a map and reduce function. It also supports multi-step jobs, if you need to map-reduce more then once.

For the problem you described I think you could write a multi-step job to solve the problem. You would pass V as a parameter to the job.

- Map 1   - For each edge (a,b) yield (a, (a,b)) and (b, (a, b)
- Reduce 1 - You'll have a list of edges some of which start with a, and some
  which end with a. Yield both (a, [(a, c)]) and (a, [(b, a), (a, c)]

You now have all paths of length 1 and 2. Repeat in another step to get all paths of length 1 to 3. Your final reduce can discard anything that doesn't start with v, and return all the paths (v, ui)

Comment: I forget to say that i use dumbo package.